# i can't save data in lcoal storage when i refresh the page

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

Where is the problem, I can't save data in local storage when i refresh the page and it saved when i clicked but the problem it disappear i used usestate data to keep hook i don't know why i tried all solutions and nothing worked i think the problem released because i use redux and that didn't work well or something else or useeffect didn't work for some reason

```
import { Button, Col, Container, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "./Watchstemp.css"
import { FaEye, FaWindowClose } from "react-icons/fa";
import { addTowatched } from "../rtk/reducers/Watchedslice";
import { clearMovie } from "../rtk/reducers/watchSlice";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Watchstemp(){
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const posts = useSelector(poster => poster)
    const [posters, setPosters] = useState(posts.postSlice)
    useEffect(() => {
        // storing input name
        localStorage.setItem("watchlist", JSON.stringify(posters));
      }, [posters]); // Update the dependency array with posters
      
      useEffect(() => {
        const data = window.localStorage.getItem('watchlist');
        setPosters(data ? JSON.parse(data) : posts.postSlice);
      }, []);
    return(
        <>
            <Row>
                    { 
                posters.map((post => {
                    return (
                        <Col lg={3} md={4} sm={6} key={post}>
                        <div className="movie-cards">
                            <div className="overlay">
                                <img className="img-fluid rounded" src={post} alt={post} />
                                <div className="inner-card-controls">
                                    <FaEye className="ctrl-btn" onClick={() => dispatch(addTowatched(post))} />
                                    <FaWindowClose className="ctrl-btn" onClick={() => dispatch(clearMovie(post))}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </Col>
                    )
                }))
            }
            </Row>
        </>
    )
}
export default Watchstemp
```

Comment: You store empty list here I guess `localStorage.setItem("watchlist", JSON.stringify(posters));`

Comment: hello thank you for your comment i already have that inside useeffect        useEffect(() => {
        // storing input name
        localStorage.setItem("watchlist", JSON.stringify(posters));
      }, [posters]);

Comment: Yes I know, that's why your code doesn't work

Comment: i did that now and code still doesn't work